# How to assign data in directive in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking at John Papa style for the angular best practice.
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives

However, I have a question for his directive style.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myExample', myExample);

function myExample() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/feature/example.directive.html',
        scope: {
            max: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        controller: ExampleController,
        // note: This would be 'ExampleController' (the exported controller name, as string)
        // if referring to a defined controller in its separate file.
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true // because the scope is isolated
    };

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log('LINK: scope.min = %s *** should be undefined', scope.min);
        console.log('LINK: scope.max = %s *** should be undefined', scope.max);
        console.log('LINK: scope.vm.min = %s', scope.vm.min);
        console.log('LINK: scope.vm.max = %s', scope.vm.max);
    }
}

ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ExampleController($scope) {
    // Injecting $scope just for comparison
    var vm = this;

    vm.min = 3;

    console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.min = %s', $scope.vm.min);
    console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.max = %s', $scope.vm.max);
    console.log('CTRL: vm.min = %s', vm.min);
    console.log('CTRL: vm.max = %s', vm.max);
}


<!-- example.directive.html -->
<div>hello world</div>
<div>max={{vm.max}}<input ng-model="vm.max"/></div>
<div>min={{vm.min}}<input ng-model="vm.min"/></div>
```

In his example, he has both controller and directive in one file. My question is how do I know which portion of my codes go under `linkFunc` and which go under `ExampleController`? For example, if I want to inject a service, should I add it to `linkFunc`? If I receive a collection of data, should I use `scope.data` under `linkFucn` or `vm.data` under controller? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here few principles to consider:

- > The basic difference is that controller can expose an API, and link functions can interact with controllers using require. **Best Practice**: *use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.* [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- write business logic in controller and DOM manipulation in link

More straight forward answer:

Since `$scope`(in controller) == `vm`(in controller) == `scope`(in link), you can do both scope.data under linkFucn or vm.data.

You are not injecting services into link function, rather into controller.

Just my understanding ...